# Why is pipenv telling me the wrong version of python?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pipenv, virtualenvwrapper

I created a virtual environment using:

```
mkvirtualenv env_name --python=python3.9
```

Then I tried to install from Pipfile:

```
pipenv install --dev
```

But I got the following error:

```
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.UnsupportedPythonVersion: pylint requires Python '~=3.6' but the running Python is 2.7.17
```

I checked my python version and it is correct:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.9.1
```

Why is it telling me that my python version is 2.7.17? This is not happening when I install using the following command:

```
pip install pylint==2.7.2
```

Comment: Unix systems usually have more than one Python version. Just because your personal login shell uses Python 3.9 by default does not mean that other tools installed previously or with different environment will use the same version.

Comment: What is `mkvirtualenv`? `pipenv` already creates the virtual env as part of `pipenv install`. You pass `--python=/path/to/python` to `pipenv`.

Comment: @GinoMempin `mkvirtualenv` is a shell function from `virtualenvwrapper` (I just added the tag) to create a virtual env managed by `virtualenvwrapper`.

Answer (score 7):

First, let's clarify your workflow for using `pipenv` to manage virtual environments.

With `pipenv`, you don't need to separately create your virtual environment with `mkvirtualenv` or with whatever virtualenv utility you have. The basic flow is to simply do `pipenv install`:

[Example Pipenv Workflow](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#example-pipenv-workflow)

> Clone / create project repository:
>
> ```
> $ cd myproject
> ```
>
> Install from Pipfile, if there is one:
>
> ```
> $ pipenv install
> ```
>
> Or, add a package to your new project:
>
> ```
> $ pipenv install <package>
> ```
>
> This will create a `Pipfile` if one doesn’t exist. If one does exist, it
> will automatically be edited with the new package you provided.
>
> Next, activate the Pipenv shell:
>
> ```
> $ pipenv shell 
> $ python --version
> ```
>
> This will spawn a new shell subprocess, which can be deactivated by
> using exit.

That should create the virtual environment *and* install your dependencies in one command. The auto-created virtual env folder is [based on the path of the current directory where you ran the command](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#virtualenv-mapping-caveat):

> - The virtualenv is stored globally with the name of the project’s root directory plus the hash of the full path to the project’s root
>   (e.g., `my_project-a3de50`).
> - If you change your project’s path, you break such a default mapping and pipenv will no longer be able to find and to use the project’s
>   virtualenv.

I'm guessing that the reason why you do a `mkvirtualenv` separately is to control where the virtual env folder is stored/managed. `pipenv` provides options for that as well:

[Custom Virtual Environment Location](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-virtual-environment-location)

> Pipenv automatically honors the `WORKON_HOME` environment variable, if
> you have it set — so you can tell pipenv to store your virtual
> environments wherever you want, e.g.:
>
> ```
> $ export WORKON_HOME=~/.venvs
> ```
>
> In addition, you can also have Pipenv stick the virtualenv in
> `project/.venv` by setting the `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` environment
> variable.

From what you tried with

```
$ mkvirtualenv env_name --python=python3.9
```

The [mkvirtualenv](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#mkvirtualenv) reference says that means "create an `env_name` in the `WORKON_HOME` folder". When you did `pipenv install`, **it's NOT going to use that same virtual env directory**, because as described above, it auto-generates the virtual env directory based on the "*name of the project’s root directory plus the hash of the full path to the project’s root*". So whatever happened in `env_name` is ignored.

With `pipenv` you simply have to set the `WORKON_HOME` folder then `pipenv install` should create your virtual env under that same folder. Every time you need to activate it, you `cd` into your project directory, then do `pipenv shell`.

Now, for the Python version problem. By default, when you do `pipenv install`, it uses whatever is listed as the `python_version` on your Pipfile, such as this:

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

It scans your system and looks for a compatible python installation. Now, it seems you already have an existing Pipfile that has `"2.7"` on it. Or it could be that there's already an existing virtual environment (created by a previous `pipenv install` call and Python 2.7 was used). Whatever the case, even though you `mkvirtualenv`-ed an `env_name` with Python 3.9, that one is ignored as I already mentioned, and `pipenv` still used the Python 2.7 version, which resulted in that error:

```
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.UnsupportedPythonVersion:  ...
```

To fix this, start over by deleting any pre-existing virtual environments by using `--rm`:

```
$ cd yourproject
$ pipenv --rm
Removing virtualenv (/path/to/.venvs/myproject-wv1hzz4Y)...
```

Then check that your existing Pipfile has the correct version set in `python_version`.

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

Normally, you don't have to manually set the version, if you originally used `pipenv install` correctly. To specify the correct version, you need to pass in a [`--python`](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/#cmdoption-pipenv-python) option, similar to what you did with `mkvirtualenv`:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.9.2

$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
   
$ pipenv install --python=/usr/local/bin/python3 
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
...
Using /usr/local/bin/python3 (3.9.2) to create virtualenv...

$ pipenv shell
$ python -V
Python 3.9.2
```

If there is no Pipfile yet, `pipenv` will create one and set `python_version` correctly.